# Matlab solve function returning 0

Tags: matlab

I want to find the values for Cm and Cg however i think i'm calling the function wrong since only the values that return are 0. Any suggestions?

```
syms Cm Cg

R = 10000;
Cs = 2.2*10^-12;
Vs = 20;
Vv = 0.204;
W = 2*pi*10000;

Equation = (Vs/Vv)*((i*W*Cm*(R/2))/(1+(i*W*Cm*(R/2)*(1+((Cg+Cs)/Cm))))) == 0;
[Cm, Cg] = solve(Equation)
```

Comment: How do you expect to get a solution for two variables out of one equation?

Comment: You have two variables and one equation! You need to have at least two equations to solve for to two variables.